# Weird Behavior from Redefining Ruby Method

Tags: ruby

Why is the output of the program:

```
require 'set'

class Set
  alias :old_add :add
  def add(arg)
    arg = 5
    old_add arg
  end
end

s = Set.new ([1,2])
s.add(3)

puts s.inspect
```

being

```
#<Set: {5}>
```

as opposed to

```
#<Set: {1,2,5}>
```

The method `add` is redefined to run with argument `5`.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source of [`Set::new`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-c-new):

```
# File set.rb, line 80
def initialize(enum = nil, &block) # :yields: o
  @hash ||= Hash.new

  enum.nil? and return

  if block
    do_with_enum(enum) { |o| add(block[o]) }
  else
    # you did not supply any block, when you called `new`
    # thus else part will be executed here
    merge(enum)
  end
end
```

it seems that `Set.new` calls method `#add` internally. In the OP's example, `block` is `nil`, thus [`#merge`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/set/rdoc/Set.html#method-i-merge) is called:

```
# File set.rb, line 351
def merge(enum)
  if enum.instance_of?(self.class)
    @hash.update(enum.instance_variable_get(:@hash))
  else
    # in your case this else part will be executed.
    do_with_enum(enum) { |o| add(o) }
  end

  self
end
```

Hence `add` is called for each element of `enum` (`[1,2]`). Here, you overrode the original `#add` method, and within that method, you are calling the old `#add` method with the argument `5`.

Set implements a collection of **unordered values with no duplicates**. Thus even if you added `5` twice, you are getting only one `5`. This is the reason you are not getting `#<Set: {1,2}>`, but `#<Set: {5}>`. As below, when you call `Set.new`, the object `#<Set: {5}>` is created just as I explained above:

```
require 'set'

class Set
  alias :old_add :add
  def add(arg)
    arg = 5
    old_add arg
  end
end

s = Set.new ([1,2])
s # => #<Set: {5}>
```

When you called `s.add(3)`, your overridden `add` method was called, and it again passed the `5` to the old `add` method. As I said earlier, `Set` doesn't contain duplicate values, thus  the object will still be the same as the earlier `#<Set: {5}>`.

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate a new set with given members, the members are added using the `add` method. This can be shown by investigating the set after creating it:

```
Set.new([1,2])
# => #<Set: {5}>
```

Thus, when you do `s.add(3)` you basically add `5` again, which has already been added twice to the set and therefore the method doesn't actually change the set.